# Why do we lose control momentarily?

Tags: social-psychology, psychology

We may be able to control our temper most of the times, but there are times when on the spur of the moment we react the way we don't want to. Yet we do so. Why are we not able to carry our conditioned behavior to the situations where we get pushed too far? Is it possible to have 100% control?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has a personal threshold of self-control. This threshold is unique for each one of us and is dependant on personality, experience and context. When this threshold is surpassed, we react viscerally without thinking too much.

Zillman's excitation transfer theory can explain, at some extent, why we surpass our self-control threshold.

> Excitation-transfer theory purports that residual excitation from one stimulus will amplify the excitatory response to another stimulus, though the hedonic valences of the stimuli may differ[1] (Bryant & Miron, 2003). The excitation-transfer process is not limited to a single emotion [2](cf. Zillmann, 1983, 1996, 1998). For example, when watching a movie, a viewer may be angered by seeing the hero wronged by the villain, but this initial excitation may intensify the viewer's pleasure in witnessing the villain's punishment later.
>
> Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excitation-transfer_theory

According to Zillman, the residual excitation produced by a stimulus may be transfered and amplify the excitatory response to another stimulus. The best example we can know about this is sports. When practicing a sport (i.e.: hockey) your excitation levels rise because of the physical activation consequence of the excersice. Part of this activation may be transfered to the excitatory response to another stimulus, for instance, an argument in the pitch. This could explains why arguments during a match (whatever the sport is) may sometimes end in physical aggression.

In my humble opinion one of the keys to self-control  is to be aware of your excitement levels and specially to know what stimulus generates your activation. This will help you to control your activation levels so it doesn't transfer to another unrelated situations. For instance, if you had a bad day at work and you are feeling upset, you are more likely to feel angry about things that normally wouldn't bother you that much. However, if you are able to be conscious of your activation state and it's cause, you may be able to avoid this to transfer to other situations.

Comment: What's the source of the quote?